How to get count values array1 in array2
I have a table:
CREATE TABLE T (
  order_id Integer PRIMARY KEY,
  items_current_order Integer[],
  items_next_order Integer[]
);

INSERT INTO T(order_id, items_current_order, items_next_order) VALUES (4254677, '{1, 1, 1}', '{1, 1}');
INSERT INTO T(order_id, items_current_order, items_next_order) VALUES (4254645, '{1,2,5,6}', '{1,1,6}');

I need to count the number of elements of items_next_order included in items_current_order.
The result that I expect:



client_id
order_id
items_current_order
items_next_order
count




905562
4254677
{1, 1, 1}
{1, 1}
2


905562
4254645
{1, 2, 5, 6}
{1, 1, 6}
2



For example, for order_id = 4254645, the result (count) should be 2, since only 2 of the values items_next_order (1, 6) are included in the items_current_order.
The second {1} from items_next_order is not included because there is only one in the items_current_order.
I'm trying something like that:
select 
     order_id
     , items_current_order
     , items_next_order
    , (SELECT 
    COUNT(case when arr=matches then matches end)
    FROM unnest(items_current_order) arr cross join unnest(items_next_order)  matches
    where arr is not null and matches is not null )
from T


Why is your question tagged with [tag:postgresql-9.3], [tag:postgresql-9.4] and [tag:postgresql-9.5]? Which PostgreSQL version are you really using? (As 9.3 - 9.5 are ancient and no longer supported.)

@Mark Rotteveel I'm using postgres 14

I'll try to break down this problem for you:

For a number to be counted, it needs to appear in both the first array, A and the second array, B.
For any integer in A or B, the final count for that particular integer is the minimum of its count in A and B. To put this into perspective:

Case 1 - A = {1, 1};  B = {1,}, the count will be 1.
Case 2 - A = {1,}; B = {1,}, the count will be 1.
Case 3 - A = {1,}; B = {1,1}, the count will be 1.
From case 1 and case 3, you can see that one of the arrays becomes the "limiting reagent".
So, I propose a solution that gets the minimum of the count of every distinct integer in A and B and adds it up.
The SQL code might look something like this:
select order_id, items_current_order, items_next_order, (
    with a as (
        select num, count(*) as a_count from unnest(items_current_order) num group by num
    ), b as (
        select num, count(*) as b_count from unnest(items_next_order) num group by num
    ) select sum(least(a_count, b_count))
    from b
    inner join a on a.num = b.num
) from t;


You can check not only item(current_order)=item(next_order). Necessary check count of equal items and take min value.
See example.
select order_id, items_current_order, items_next_order
  ,(select count(*) 
    from
     (
      select ci,row_number()over(partition by ci order by ci)cin 
      from unnest(t.items_current_order) ci
     )co
    inner join (
      select ni,row_number()over(partition by ni order by ni)nin 
      from unnest(t.items_next_order) ni
     )cn on ci=ni and cin=nin
  ) as cnt
from T 

Internal output for clarity



order_id
items_current_order
items_next_order
ci
cin
ni
nin




4254677
{1,1,1}
{1,1}
1
1
1
1


4254677
{1,1,1}
{1,1}
1
2
1
2


4254645
{1,2,5,6}
{1,1,6}
1
1
1
1


4254645
{1,2,5,6}
{1,1,6}
6
1
6
1




select 
  T.order_id
  , items_current_order
  , items_next_order
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN arr.arr=matches.arr THEN 1 END)
from T
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT order_id, arr.*
            FROM T
            CROSS JOIN unnest(T.items_current_order) arr) arr on arr.ordeR_id=T.order_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT order_id, arr.*
            FROM T
            CROSS JOIN unnest(T.items_next_order) arr)  matches on matches.ordeR_id=T.order_id
WHERE arr.arr=matches.arr
GROUP BY
  T.order_id
  , items_current_order
  , items_next_order

output:



order_id
items_current_order
items_next_order
count




4254645
{1,2,5,6}
{1,1,6}
2


4254677
{1,1,1}
{1,1}
1



see: DBFIDDLE
Now i just need to explain why a count 1 for order 4254677 should be correct.... (but I cannot do so.... )

Because  of the first value 1 of items_next_order will correspond to the first value of items_current_order, the second value 1 of items_next_order the second of items_current_order.

Yes, i know, but when taking distinct values (1,2,5,6 matching to 1,6 will give 2), but on next order (1 matching to 1) will give 1. when not doing distinct on items_next_order the answer is 1,2,5,6 match to 1,1,6 which will give a count of 3, which is also not correct.

In the first example, we get 2, not 3, because after we have found a match for the first 1 from "items_next_order" in  "items_current_order", these values should be eliminated from further matching. Therefore, for the second value of 1 from the  "items_next_order", there will be no match in the "items_current_order". Thanks for the help.

My problem is "eliminated from further matching"
